# Validity of thermal average approximation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, approximations, leptogenesis

I'm following [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.09956) about leptogenesis and heavy sterile neutrinos, and the authors define the thermal average of a general momentum-dependent variable $X(k)$ as:

$$\langle X\rangle=\frac{2}{n_{N_{1}, \mathrm{eq}}} \int \frac{d^{3} \mathbf{k}}{(2 \pi)^{3}} X(k) f_{F}(k)$$

where $n_{N_{1}, \mathrm{eq}}$ is the equilibrium number density of the sterile neutrinos,

$$n_{N_{1}, \mathrm{eq}}=\left.2 \int \frac{\mathrm{d}^{3} \mathbf{k}}{(2 \pi)^{3}} f_{F}(k)\right|_{k^{0}=\sqrt{\mathbf{k}^{2}+M_{1}^{2}}}$$

Then, they implement the thermal averaging by replacing:

$$\gamma(k) \rightarrow\langle\gamma\rangle, \quad \tilde{\gamma}(k) \rightarrow\langle\tilde{\gamma}\rangle, \quad \text { and } \quad \beta k_{0}\left(\gamma^{2}(k)-\tilde{\gamma}^{2}(k)\right) \rightarrow\left\langle\beta k_{0}\left(\gamma^{2}-\tilde{\gamma}^{2}\right)\right\rangle$$

where $\gamma$ and $\tilde\gamma$ are momentum-dependent rates and $k_0=\sqrt{\mathbf{k}^{2}+M_{1}^{2}}$.

Then, the authors proceed to make the following approximation:

$$\left\langle\beta k_{0}\left(\gamma^{2}-\tilde{\gamma}^{2}\right)\right\rangle \approx\left\langle\beta k_{0}\right\rangle\langle\gamma+\tilde{\gamma}\rangle\langle\gamma-\tilde{\gamma}\rangle$$

**Here is my question:** Mathematically speaking, what are the conditions (or assumptions) making the approximation valid, if any?